# Using jQuery load() on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I'm trying to load content into a DIV with jQuery `load()` but it is not working if the link that calls the function is generated after page load.

```
var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='ajax-loader.gif' alt='loading...' />";
$(".slide_more").click(function() {
    $("#ajaxcontent").html(ajax_load).load('p=4324.php #singlePost');
});
```

and the generated link:

```
<a href="#" class="slide_more" id="load_basic">LOAD</a>
```

I've tried using `live()` and `delegate()` with no luck:

```
$(".slide_more").live('click', function() {
    $("#ajaxcontent").html(ajax_load).load('p=4324.php #singlePost');
});
```

The strange thing is that the `.slide_more` class also calls a simple jQuery toggle which is working with `live()`.

Comment: Have you use firebug to see if the ajax call works? I suspect your url is being misinterpreted.

Comment: the generated link is generated after page load. this code must be executed after link is generated

Comment: Yes, under the NET/XHR nothing appears except the generated content that contains the link.

Comment: Yes it is inside (document).ready()

Comment: @elbatron: Nothing is wrong with the code you've posted. Can you put an `alert` in the first line of the `.slide_more` handler to check whether the handler isn't firing, or the ajax request isn't completing.

Comment: @elbatron: Furthermore, because you're adding the link to your page dynamically (I assume dynamically == after the page has loaded), you are right in using `delegate` or `live` over `click`.

Comment: Galchen, I guess you are right, how can I ensure that this piece of code is executed only after the generated link (by pure javascript) is loaded? And if that's the case, how come that toggle works?

Comment: @Matt alert only works without live() or delegate(). If the triggering link is not in the generated content but outside on the page, everything is working fine.

Comment: @elbatron: http://jsfiddle.net/mattlunn/2ytnW/. You're barking up the wrong tree. If the image path/ AJAX url existed in my Fiddle, it'd work fine.

Comment: @Matt, thanks. As I mentioned it works fine if .slide_more is outside of the javascript generated content. Actually the dynamically generated content is from a parsed XML... To be honest, I don't understand why it is not working...

Comment: Ok guys! Got the problem, I just moved the script to the header from the footer, and now it works the way I wanted! Thanks for reassuring me that the script is OK, and the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @elbatron: You should add your fix as an answer, and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The jQery snippet with the live() handler added to click() event is working fine. I just had to make sure that the code is at the top of the page before any other code.